# Why does my JS audio-streaming code sound different on x86 and x86_64 systems?

Tags: javascript, binary, streaming, web-audio-api, endianness

My app streams PCM binary data from the server to the Web Audio API.

To normalize the audio, I use a DataView to cast the incoming data to Int16, divide each sample by 32768, before casting them back to Float32 for playback:

```
var data = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

var tempArray = new Int16Array(data.byteLength / Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

var len = tempArray.length;
for (var jj = 0; jj < len; ++jj) {
    tempArray[jj] = data.getInt16(jj * Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, true);
}


var bufferToPlay = new Float32Array(tempArray.length);
var channelCounter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length;) {
    var normalizedAudio = tempArray[i] / 32768;
    i = i + 1;
    bufferToPlay[channelCounter] = normalizedAudio;
    channelCounter++;
}
```

Here's the weirdness:

When I run this on my 64 bit Win machine, the audio is flawless. But when I use my old 32 bit Win XP machine, the audio is full of what sound like resampling / bit conversion artifacts.

I've been reading a lot about endianness, but both machines are Pentium so should both be little-endian, right? So how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check `sampleRate` for the WebAudio context on each machine.  Are they the same?  Plus, if the endianness were wrong, it wouldn't sound like resampling/bit conversion.  If it sounds like resampling, then the sample rates for the two machines are very probably different.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Turns out it was a mismatch of soundcard sampling rates.